# Hyperparameter tuning in XGBoost

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to do parameter tuning in XGBoost. However when I run the code it gets stuck and never finishes. The dataset I am using has 50000 rows and 35 columns. Am I doing something wrong or is it too computationally expensive?

```
param_test1 = [{
 'max_depth':[3],
 'min_child_weight':[3]
}]

gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = XGBClassifier(learning_rate =0.1, n_estimators=140, max_depth=5,
                                              min_child_weight=1, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8,
                                              objective= 'binary:logistic', nthread=4, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=27), 
                    param_grid = param_test1, scoring='roc_auc',n_jobs=4,iid=False, cv=5)

target = 'AntAktAvtBank'
predictors = [x for x in dtrain.columns if x not in [target, ID_col]]
gsearch1.fit(dtrain[predictors],dtrain[target])
gsearch1.grid_scores_, gsearch1.best_params_, gsearch1.best_score_
```

Comment: What are the versions of xgboost and scikit-learn?

Comment: Have you tried n_jobs=1 (single thread) or n_jobs=-1 (auto-detect number of threads)? XGBoost hangs or behave very strange in my case if I provide any other numbers.

Comment: Same here as @CrazyElf. Even after making sure that the multi-threading version of xgboost is installed and configured correctly, the issue remains.

Comment: This [issue at xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/512) and [this at scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6627) discuss this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks! For me it worked with n_jobs=1

Comment: @Emilie do you mean n_jobs=-1? Running it on a single thread should lead to a slowdown.